# why splashactivity Blinking when mainactivity start

Tags: android

[image]

It's my project situation now.

1. MainActivity is LAUNCHER
2. SplashActivity called MainActivity onCreate()

When I think about it, it looks like there is no problem.
but after app starting, 
The `MainActivity` screen is briefly visible before `SplashActivity` call.

Surprisingly, I did not see it on other devices, only galaxy s8.

Of course, I know it is not a general structure. But I can not understand it because I have been working normally.
white color is cold start style and splashActivity.
red color is mainActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // some getIntent code

    startActivityForResult(new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class), RESULTCODE_);

    setInitLayout();
}
```

manifest

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" >
</activity>
```

minSdkVersion 21

targetSdkVersion 28

Comment: Have you try to call the `setContentView` and `setInitLayout` after starting the `IntroActivity`?

Comment: share your splash theme code please

Comment: The thing is splashactivity should be the launcher and should come before the main activity.

Comment: @Tam Huynh I try to call the setContentView and setInitLayout after starting the IntroActivity.. same

Comment: @ismail alaoui <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/intro_background</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="23">true</item>
    </style>

Comment: @ismail alaoui  intro_background add image and background color

Comment: please read my answer

Comment: @Gourav Must splashactivity be a luncherActivity?

Comment: Ya because launcher activity is the first activity on the mobile app and you set main activity as launcher activity but you set splash activity to launch first so there is a clash

Comment: Heh. Don't listen them. you done all right. just for splash screen if you use  style with <item name="android:windowBackground"> you dont nedd to call setContentView(R.layout.activity_main). remove this string and all will be good

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use a splash screen that way . This should be strictly avoided.

With this approach you may also lead the **problem of blank white page appears during splash launching** and this what exactly happened to you  !

i advice you to read [this](https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154) article and try to make your splash screen in the right way to avoid such behavior !

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. 
If so, should splashactivity be a luncherActivitiy?

Comment: If the splashActivity is luncherActivity, is it possible to bypass the splashActivity?

Comment: If you have to look at main activity immediately,
Is it possible to ignore luncher activity?

Comment: yes you can ignore it if you don't need set some progress before the application setup

Comment: Is there a way to ignore the luncher activity?

Comment: make your mainActivity luncher , and dont call splash anymore

Answer (score 1):

If you use style with `android:windowBackground` for splash activity, don't call `setContentView()`. Thats all!

Answer (score 0):

You have placed MainActivity class to be the launcher activity in your manifest. I am assuming that your splashscreen activity is called SplashActivity. If you want it to be shown before as the SplashScreen and then MainActivity to come later on, change your manifest code to be:

```xml
<activity android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
       <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" >
</activity>

<activity android:name=".IntroActivity"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme" >
</activity>
```

Then create your SplashActivity as suggested by Ismail in the link that  [he has provided](https://android.jlelse.eu/right-way-to-create-splash-screen-on-android-e7f1709ba154)

Comment: It is not a good idea to use a splash screen that wastes a user’s time like that !

Comment: I have always used this approach and it has never given me any issues. I will however try to give the approach that you have suggested a try. Thanks.

Comment: splash screen isn't used to show information about application  before the main activity , this called a walkthrough ,  splash screen normally used to display some kind of progress before the application setup completely (check if user is logged , set up settings ,.....)  and it duration depends on progress not on fixed time

Answer (score 0):

Use this thread code for splash activity. It will better work :

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                public  void run(){
                    try{
                        sleep(3000);

                    }catch (InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally {
                        Intent mainAct=new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(mainAct);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            };
            thread.start();

        }


        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {

            super.onDestroy();

        }

    }
```

Comment: If you have to look at main activity immediately, Is it possible to ignore luncher activity(SplashActivity )?

Comment: you can reduce time  sleep(3000); or directly launch main activity .

Comment: how? add flag in try catch?

Comment: you did wrong code of manifest i see your manifest class kindly have a look at my manifest class n follow that code your issue will be resolved

Comment: call <intent launcher> in main activtiy for directly call main activtiy.

Comment: I dont know . you manifest splash activity is launcher. My question is Is it possible to ignore luncher activity(SplashActivity)?

Comment: yes you can you can directly launch main activity .

Comment: Please tell me how.... launcher activity = splash activity, when app starting, ignore luncher activity(splashActivity), not visible splash activity, direct call main activity..

Comment: in manifest call launcher in main activity like this                                           <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Comment: and please see my code which i post for your query. you will understand for manifest

Answer (score 0):

Use this thread code for splash activity it will better work -

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 3000;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

            Thread thread = new Thread() {
                public  void run(){
                    try{
                        sleep(3000);

                    }catch (InterruptedException e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }finally {
                        Intent mainAct=new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                        startActivity(mainAct);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            };
        thread.start();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy();

    }

}


and your manifest class will be look like this : 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.diskapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning"> 
      <activity android:name=".Activities.SplashActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

**simply add handler for limited seconds of time and finish current activity**

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //actvity transaction
            }
        },3000);
```